# Compare two rows in one column R

Tags: r

I want to compare values that are listed in one column over two rows in R. The rows are identified through an ID variable. I want to produce a new variable that tells me which of both values is lower than the other. Here an example:

```
value   id   new_var
    1    1     lower
    2    1    higher
    5    2    higher
    3    2     lower
   10    3     lower
   11    3    higher
    2    4     lower
    1    4    higher
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are more than two elements per group, do a group by, and create a condition with `ifelse/case_when` to create the 'new_var'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(new_var = case_when(value == max(value) ~ "higher",
      TRUE ~ "lower")) %>% 
  ungroup
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  value    id new_var
  <int> <int> <chr>  
1     1     1 lower  
2     2     1 higher 
3     5     2 higher 
4     3     2 lower  
5    10     3 lower  
6    11     3 higher 
7     2     4 higher 
8     1     4 lower
```

---

An option is also to `arrange` and then create a new column in the order with `rep` (assuming 2 elements per id)

```
df1 %>%
  arrange(id, value) %>% 
  mutate(new_var = rep(c("lower", "higher"), length.out = n()))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(value = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 1L), id = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe, it would be better for me to ask a new question, but this answer got me thinking. What if you wanted the new column to be the difference between values? The first value for each group would need to be NA because it doesn't have a value before it. Then the rest of the values for an id would be the difference (Value(i) - Value(i-1)).

Comment: @Tanner33 it would be `value - lag(value)`?

Comment: Amazing. I wish I would have thought of that years ago instead of using for loops. Thank you @akrun.

Answer (score 1):

We could `mutate` a `new_var` with an `ifelse` statement conditional on `min` of `value`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(new_var = ifelse(value == min(value), "lower", NA_character_)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
    value    id new_var
  <int> <int> <chr>  
1     1     1 lower  
2     2     1 NA     
3     5     2 NA     
4     3     2 lower  
5    10     3 lower  
6    11     3 NA     
7     2     4 NA     
8     1     4 lower
```